# mysql failed fulltext search with a particular word

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I'm in trouble with a strange behavior of mysql.
If I try to search with fulltext query sam* word, I have no results back.

Ex. table companies

```
    id || name
    1  || Company name
    2  || Same Company name
```

If I make

```
`SELECT name FROM companies WHERE MATCH name AGAINST ('+Company*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`
```

It works, instead if I use

```
`SELECT name FROM companies WHERE MATCH name AGAINST ('+Sam*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`
```

or

```
`SELECT name FROM companies WHERE MATCH name AGAINST ('+Same' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`
```

I have no results!

Do you have any idea about this issue?

PS. if I use +Sa* instead of +Sam*, it works

Comment: Hi
I also have same issue with word "NVR".
did you find any solution for this issue please let me know.

Comment: I recommend reading this : http://www.hackingwithphp.com/9/3/18/advanced-text-searching-using-full-text-indexes It really help !

Answer (score 0):

You must to change the configuration value `ft_min_word_len` (fulltext min word length) the default value is set to 4.

Add (or modify) this line to mysql config /etc/my.cnf (or my.ini in windows)

```
ft_min_word_len = 3
```

After that you may call the index re-creation using the command:

```
REPAIR TABLE companies QUICK;
```

BTW: Fulltext search doesn't accept `LIKE` wildcards: `*` or `%`